# Select object from collection using OGNL in JSP

Tags: jsp, iterator, struts, selection, ognl

I would like to select an object from a collection of objects.

The collection is `#attr.studyTypeListKey`, the expression of which is correct and is saved in `applicationContext`.

The **selection condition** is, the `code` property of the object in the collection should equal the value of `study`, study is the property of each object in the iterator `proposals`.

```
   <s:iterator value="proposals">   
       <s:property value="#attr.studyTypeListKey.{^#this.code == study}.name" />
   ....
```

The code below doesn't work i.e. it displays nothing:

1. The following will display the first object in the collection, but this object actually doesn't satisfy the condition.

   ```
   <s:property value="#attr.studyTypeListKey.{?#this.code == #study}[0].name" />
   ```
2. The following also displays nothing:

   ```
   <s:property value="#attr.studyTypeListKey.{^#this.code == #study}.name" />
   ```